# "Wow, I've never seen such a nice cell phone, Mary". Is it naturally for Mary to say: "I agree with you"?

Tags: exam-questions, conversation

This question is based on the exercise in my English textbook:

> Mark the letter A, B, C, or D on your answer sheet to indicate the most suitable response to complete each of the following exchanges.
>
> John: "Wow, I’ve never seen such a nice cell phone, Mary"
>   Mary: " ___ "
>   A. Thank you. I’m glad you like it.
>   B. Oh, I don’t know.
>   C. I agree with you.
>   D. You’re welcome.

The answer key is option A (Thank you. I’m glad you like it). However, I think this response is suitable only if that cell phone belongs to Mary. If that cell phone doesn't belong to Mary, is it natural for her to say "I agree with you" (option C) when she has the same opinion as John?

Comment: Yes. You clearly understand much better than test-writers (who are not an imaginative crew) that Context is Critical!

Comment: E.  I shoplifted it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A B or C could be reasonable responses, in context.

That said I would have chosen 'A', as the natural reading is that John is complementing Mary, and 'A' is a reasonable response.

> A: {Mary shows John her new phone}
>   John "Wow, I’ve never seen such a nice cell phone, Mary"
>   Mary {grateful for the compliment} Thank-you,  I’m glad you like it.
>
> B: {Mary and John are in a phone shop. John points out the new galaxy}
>   John "Wow, I’ve never seen such a nice cell phone, Mary"
>   Mary: Oh, I don't know...
>   John: What do you mean?
>   Mary: I've heard that they can overheat.
>
> C: {Mary and John are in a phone shop. John points out the new galaxy}
>   John "Wow, I’ve never seen such a nice cell phone, Mary"
>   Mary I agree with you.
>   John: But I thought you were an Apple fan!?
>   Mary: Yes, but the screen on this one is so much nicer.

Comment: Even D could be a reasonable response in context.  Perhaps it is a gift from Mary to John and she's just about to hand it to him (or has already done so).

Comment: maybe, but that's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I'm not sure what B (Oh, I don’t know) really means in this context. I guess its meaning may be "Oh, I don't know. I do not completely agree. For me, that cell phone is not really so nice". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Something like that. I've added examples that could fit the context for A, B and C. I still think D is "a bit of a stretch"

Comment: My English is not good enough for me to understand your phrase "a bit of a stretch". Could you kindly explain that phrase in a simpler way for English learners like me to understand? Thanks a lot

Comment: It means it requires some extraordinary belief: D could be a correct response, but the context seems very unlikely, I don't believe such a context could ever arise naturally.